# Salt SLS remove last octect of IP address from grain

Tags: yaml, jinja2, salt-stack

I'm trying to match conditions based on the third octet of an IP address since Windows minions don't report the gateway. I can get the grain info for the IP and match the full IP like below but I only want to match to the third octet:

```
{% set subnet = salt['grains.get']('ipv4:0')  %}
user_coinfig:
  cmd.run:
    {% if subnet == '10.1.244.146' %}
    - name: |
        cmd.exe net localgroup administrators user /add
    {% elif subnet == '10.1.245.146' %}
    - name: |
        cmd.exe net localgroup administrators user /add
    {% endif %}
```

Desired state:

```
{% set subnet = salt['grains.get']('ipv4:0')  %}
user_coinfig:
  cmd.run:
    {% if subnet == '10.1.244' %}
    - name: |
        cmd.exe net localgroup administrators user /add
    {% elif subnet == '10.1.245' %}
    - name: |
        cmd.exe net localgroup administrators user /add
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: This code seems to be for one time use, i.e. it will error out if run again. Please look at Salt state [group](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.group.html) to "*manage*" groups and members.

Comment: true, this is for one time deployment config within aria. thanks for the link though @seshadri_c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Jinja is a templating language based on Python, you do have access to all of the `string` methods of Python.
And for this case, you can use the method [`startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).

So, you can do:

```
{% if subnet.startswith('10.1.244.') %}
- name: |
    cmd.exe net localgroup administrators user /add
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

For actual subnet (not just prefix) matching, there is [`network.in_subnet`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.network.html#salt.modules.network.in_subnet) for the current host, and [`network.ip_in_subnet`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.network.html#salt.modules.network.ip_in_subnet) for arbitrary IP addresses.

```yaml
{% if salt["network.in_subnet"]("10.1.244.0/23") %}
user_coinfig:
  cmd.run:
    - name: cmd.exe net localgroup administrators user /add
{% endif %}
```

You can also get the subnets of the host directly with [`network.subnets`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.network.html#salt.modules.network.subnets), if the network topology already matches what you're looking for.

```yaml
{% if "10.1.244.0/23" in salt["network.subnets"]()  %}
user_coinfig:
  cmd.run:
    - name: cmd.exe net localgroup administrators user /add
{% endif %}
```

You could use that as a map key for more complex situations.